Starting A Lot Of Threads At The Same Time With Python
I am trying to start a lot of threads (100 of them) at the same time within the for loop and get the total time that takes to execute them with Python.
First I manually created 8 threads and started them at the same time without any problem.
A1 = threading.Thread(target=TypeA)
A2 = threading.Thread(target=TypeA)
A3 = threading.Thread(target=TypeA)
A4 = threading.Thread(target=TypeA)

B1 = threading.Thread(target=TypeB)
B2 = threading.Thread(target=TypeB)
B3 = threading.Thread(target=TypeB)
B4 = threading.Thread(target=TypeB)

programStartTime = time.time()

A1.start()
A2.start()
A3.start()
A4.start()
B1.start()
B2.start()
B3.start()
B4.start()

A1.join()
A2.join()
A3.join()
A4.join()
B1.join()
B2.join()
B3.join()
B4.join()

programEndTime = time.time()
totalProgramTime = programEndTime - programStartTime

The totalProgramTime variable was something like 2 seconds and also each of the threads' execution time were quite the same.
Then I wanted to create 100 threads.
threads={}
for i in range(50):
    threads[i] = threading.Thread(target=TypeA)

for i in range(50, 100):
    threads[i] = threading.Thread(target=TypeB)

programStartTime = time.time()

for i in range(100):
    threads[i].start()
    threads[i].join()

programEndTime = time.time()
totalProgramTime = programEndTime - programStartTime

This time threads worked sequentially and the total time was sum of all of the threads' execution times.How can I create the threads at the same time that threads could work parallel again? Do I need to create and start them manually?
I have only tried for loops I cannot think of any other solution for this and I also could not find any solution at web.

Do you understand what t.join() does? It does not do anything at all to thread t. The only thing t.join() does is, it waits for thread t to finish, and then it returns.
The reason why your threads run sequentially is, your code waits for each thread to finish before it starts the next one:
for i in range(100):
    threads[i].start()
    threads[i].join()

What you want to do instead is, first, start all of the threads, and then join all of the threads.
for i in range(100):
    threads[i].start()

for i in range(100):
    threads[i].join()


Or, even better, for t in threads: / t.start() / for t in threads: / t.join().

@TimRoberts, agreed. Your version is more stylish, most especially because it gets rid of the magic number, 100; but there are days when I feel like the best way to illustrate the problem is to show the smallest change that fixes it. Yesterday was one of those days.

I understand that clearly -- I do the same thing.  My comment is not intended to be a criticism of your answer, but rather an alterhative.
